# C: How to filter values being read into a pipe

Tags: c

I am currently working with pipes forks and file descriptors and I am currently trying to . I created a pipe and filled it with integers from 2 to n using the following loop

```
int f_descr[2];

int f=fork(); //fork

if (f>0){
    close(f_descr[0]);
    for(int i=2; i<n; i++)
            write(f_descr[1], &i, sizeof(int));
    }
    close(f_descr[1]);
}
```

The issue i'm having now is that I want the child to only  read values from the pipe that are not a factor of a certain int val. How can I go about this?

Comment: You can't. It's like filling the real pipe with numbered balls and wanting to pull only the odd-numbered ones...

Comment: Do try and make your variable names a bit more descriptive than `f`.

Comment: I think you are approching the *real* problem through another problem, it's called [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: before you can use a pipe, you need to create it.  Suggest: `if ( pipe( f_descr ) == -1 )  { perror( "pipe failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }  // implied else, pipe successful`

Comment: regarding: `if (f>0){`  You are handling the 'parent' process, but failed to handle the 'child' process and failed to handle the 'error' case

Comment: a 'pipe' is (literally) like a water pipe.  There is not jumping (seeking) in a pipe.  So either only write the usable values to the pipe OR let the child process read all the values and use some algorithm to determine which of the values to use.

Comment: regarding: "and I am currently trying to."  What are you currently trying to do?